# storing the value of linux command to a variable in groovy script (soapui)

Tags: linux, groovy, soapui

I am executing following groovy script in my soapui assertion where I am trying to store the value of the output of linux command into a variable so that I cam compare the output of linux command with expected value.My groovy is as below

```
import groovy.sql.Sql  
import java.sql.DriverManager  
import java.sql.Connection  
import javax.sql.DataSource  
import java.sql.Driver;  
import java.util.*;  
import java.text.*; 


// Executing Script to capture logs
log.info "Executing Script to capture logs"
import java.lang.Object
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session
import com.jcraft.jsch.UserInfo
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec
import java.util.Properties
def sshHost = context.expand('${#Project#Kcom}');
def sshUser = 'sshuser'
def sshPass = 'sshpass'
def sshPort = port value


/////////////////////////////
log.info "Opening connection to ${sshUser}@${sshHost}:${sshPort}"
Properties config = new Properties()

config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")

JSch jsch = new JSch()

///////////////////////////
Session s = jsch.getSession(sshUser, sshHost, sshPort)
s.setPassword(sshPass)
s.setConfig(config)
s.connect()
log.info "Connected"

Channel c = s.openChannel("exec");
    ChannelExec ce = (ChannelExec) c;

    def logerror = ce.setCommand("tail -50  <log file> | grep -i 'some string'");
    log.info logerror 
    ce.setErrStream(System.err);

    ce.connect();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ce.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      log.info(line);
    }
```

here logerror always returns null .
 how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what's wrong with your code, i just know that ant command [sshexec](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) do what you need.

so, you can see how to do it correctly by [sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ant/ant-jsch/1.8.3/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/ssh/SSHExec.java)

ps: i know that soapui includes limited `groovy-all.jar` but if you able to add full groovy library list into soapui classpath it'll possible to use `groovy.lang.AntBuilder()`:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.sshexec( 
    host:"somehost", 
    username:"dude", 
    password:"yo",
    command:"tail -50  <log file> | grep -i 'some string'",
    output: "path/to/local/output/file" 
)
```